# How to validate the checksum of the google `cloud_sql_proxy` downloaded from https://dl.google.com?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

### Background

- Google's cloudsql offering, there is a `cloud_sql_proxy` tool for remoting connecting to a SQL instance, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy)
- The installation instructions for this tool are to download a pre-compiled binary for your system directly with `curl`
- However there is no `checkum` provided in these instructions current to verify this download

### Question

How can I validate this binary before running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

- The [releases page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/releases) for the proxy provides the corresponding latest SHA256 checksums
  [image: screenshot of the cloud sql proxy releases page]
- Use the appropriate tool on your system to get the checksums and compare
- E.g. if using `shasum`:

```
$ shasum -a 256 cloud_sql_proxy

b147a642ef9564469e395f1da3eb913f5e49c00c7e32bb929be8eebe102977ff  cloud_sql_proxy
```

Comment: Cloud SQL Proxy maintainer here. Just came to +1 this answer. We recommend using the releases-page to get the latest proxy versions.